# Class "__ARCLite__" warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am implementing test units to my project based on the documentation tutorial.

I selected to create a test target when creating the project which will be used for "logic" testing, and now I am creating a second target for "application" testing and only when running Test on this second target I get this warning:

```
Class __ARCLite__ is implemented in both
/Users/.../iPhone Simulator/5.0/.../<AppName>.app/<AppName>
and /Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/<AppName>AppTests.octest/<AppName>AppTests.
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I freshly created the target using the documentation guide [Setting Up Application Unit Tests](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH20-SW6).

It also surprises me that there are no references to such "**ARCLite**" class, neither here, documentation or Google (besides some chinese site results).

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not positive, but my guess is that the `__ARCLite__` class is what deals with ARC on OS X 10.6/iOS 4 (where ARC isn't part of the system runtime). As far as this warning is concerned, I wouldn't worry about it; if you compiled both the application and the library the classes should be identical.

Comment: Yes, ARCLite is the name of the static library that gets linked into ARC apps targeting 10.6/iOS 4.x and earlier.

Comment: Awesome; go me for educated guesses. :)

Comment: Yeah, I am also sure that it stands for ARC, but the fact that there is a warning and that I should ignore it kinda bothers me. I would like to understand the logic behind it and modify the app accordingly.

Comment: @ernipiggy: ARCLite is being linked into both <AppName>.app/<AppName> and then again into <AppName>AppTests.octest/<AppName>AppTests. And since the latter is injected into the former when running tests, this presents the linker with two copies of the same symbols, and it has to pick one. That's what the warning means. In this case it's a harmless warning, since the two implementations of __ARCLite__ are identical (by virtue of coming from the exact same static library linked into both targets).

Comment: Yeah, what @KevinBallard said.

Comment: Thanks, sounds logic now. Even though warnings are always annoying =o/

Comment: I agree; I don't like them either.

Comment: Any suggestion for how to get rid of the warning?